# onActivityResult does not trigger Logger

Tags: android, android-intent

I have a little problem on my activities...
Somehow my onActivityResult method is never called, even though I think I set everything up and don't have "nohistory" or something like this in my manifest.

Activity A:

```
  @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Log.d("ASDSA","ASDSA");
}
```

Activity B:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(AddStockActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("stock", stock);
                setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
                finish();
```

The Log never gets executed...Whats wrong with my implementation?

EDIT:
Thats how I call the activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AddActivity.class);
                startActivityForResult(intent, Activity.RESULT_OK);
```

Still no action on the logging.
I am firing both intents on a button click by the way.

Comment: Show us the code where you are firing `Intent` from Activity A to Activity B

Comment: Did you start your Activity B for result or it's a normal start?

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `startActivityForResult` from Activity A instead of `startActivity` while firing `Intent`

Answer (score 1):

Start activity B for result like this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityA.this, ActivityB.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);
```

where `requestCode` is an integer to distinguish between different requests.

Comment: Change the request code for example to 1, it'd work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to invoke `ActivityB` from `ActivityA` like this -

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityA.this, ActivityB.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, <your_request_code_here>);
```

You don't need to write this in `ActivityB`

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(AddBienenstockActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
 intent.putExtra("stock", stock);
```

After doing your job just

```
            setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
            finish();
```

from `ActivityB`

Comment: Please see my post carefully. You don't need to use - Intent intent = new Intent(AddBienenstockActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
 intent.putExtra("stock", stock); Just use - setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
            finish();

Answer (score 0):

Okey guys I figured it out. I needed to change my code into this one:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AddActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

Anybody can explain why?